# Apache 2.4.9 Index of folder, some img wont load on some devices

Tags: image, apache, windows-phone

So I have been fooling around with running WAMP as a web server on my computer with a free ddns
I have a directory in my webserver that has several imgs all of them .jpgs and all approx the same dimensions. When I click on the img links in my android phone all the photos load. Same thing happens on my computer in google chrome and internet explorer. Now when I try the same thing on my girlfriends windows phone running Windows Phone 8.1 it only will open one of the photos and non of the others. The photos it does not open it returns a small img icon.

Anybody with any ideas what the heck is going on here?

Answer (score 0):

Use upper case extensions for all the images, e.g. `<img src="pic name.JPEG">`; this worked for me.